# DropdownButtonFormField reset value to initial

Tags: flutter

How do I reset or select the first value from DropdownButtonFormField?
The answer from here [How to reset value in Flutter DropdownButtonFormField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61463276/how-to-reset-value-in-flutter-dropdownbuttonformfield) is outdated and not suitable for the newer flutter version.

DropdownButtonFormField:

```
final etSkillScore1Key = GlobalKey<FormState>();
...
DropdownButtonFormField(
          key: etSkillScore1Key,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Select value'),
          onChanged: (val) async {
            setState(() {
              etSkillScore1 = val as int;
            });

            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
          },
          value: etSkillScore1,
          items: priorities2.map((db.Priority priorities) {
            return DropdownMenuItem(
              child: Text(priorities.name),
              value: priorities.value,
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
```

Button for resetting the value:

```
IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                //ERORR: Null check operator used on a null value
                etSkillScore1Key.currentState!.reset();
              },
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.close,
              ))
```

Error:

```
======== Exception caught by gesture
The following _CastError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Null check operator used on a null value
```

If I use

```
etSkillScore1Key.currentState?.reset();
```

then nothing happens

Comment: Try assigning `etSkillScore1Key` to the form as key, not the dropdown field.

Comment: The type of GlobalKey you need is a FormFieldState and not a FormState.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are not using the correct key it should be a `GlobalKey<FormFieldState>()`, but even then the `reset()` would not work.

The reason for this is because of the implementation of `DropdownButtonFormField`:

```dart
DropdownButtonFormField({
  // ...

  T? value,

  // ...
}) : super(
      // ...

      initialValue: value,

      // ...
     );
```

(source: [Flutter Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButtonFormField/DropdownButtonFormField.html))

As you can see the `value` property of `DropdownButtonFormField` is what defines the `initialValue` of the `FormField` so when you are rebuilding your form field and changing the value of `etSkillScore1` it is also changing the value of your `DropdownButtonFormField.initialValue`.

### Solution 1

If you want your `reset()` to work then you can remove the property `value` of `DropdownButtonFormField` so the `initialValue` won't change with `etSkillScore1`.

```dart
DropdownButtonFormField<int>(
  key: etSkillScore1Key,
  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Select value'),
  onChanged: (val) {
    etSkillScore1 = val;
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
  },
  // value: etSkillScore1,
  items: priorities2.map((db.Priority priorities) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<int>(
      child: Text(priorities.name),
      value: priorities.value,
    );
  }).toList(),
)
```

[Try the full example on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=3b7c68a63dd4859acb95c67d76c29230&null_safety=true)

### Solution 2

Do not set the `value` property with `etSkillScore1`, if you want to initialize your widget with an initial value then do it like this:

```dart
DropdownButtonFormField<int>(
  key: etSkillScore1Key,
  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Select value'),
  onChanged: (val) {
    etSkillScore1 = val;
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
  },
  value: 1, // Use a fixed value that won't change
  items: priorities2.map((db.Priority priorities) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<int>(
      child: Text(priorities.name),
      value: priorities.value,
    );
  }).toList(),
)
```

As your `value` will be fixed then when `DropdownButtonFormField` is rebuild it will keep `1` as its initial value.